# How to save images in python in different directories?

Tags: python, image, save

This code make images in a loop. I want to save every image in its own directory. For example I want to put `img1` in `img1` folder, `img2` in `img2` folder and so on. I want to use the index in my loop as suffix.

```
 img = makeImage(g2_value,width=512)
        with open('%d.png' % i, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(img)
```

Comment: typos and better explanation of the problem.

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve) and or format again your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.mkdir` to create the directory. Then write the image to the proper path.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir

```
os.mkdir(str(i))
with open('%d/%d.png' % (i,i), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is write a function that accept `fn` as input as example `saveImg(fn, ...)` and then create folder if they doesn't exist. Be very careful cos you might overwrite previous work.

```
import os
if os.path.exists("data") is False:
    os.mkdir("data")

fldr_template = "data/img{}"

for i in range(10):
    fldr = fldr_template.format(i)
    if os.path.exists(fldr) is False:
        os.mkdir(fldr)
    fn = "data/img{}/img{0}.png".format(i)
    # here you write your file to fn
    saveImg(fn, ...)
```